# GNU Public License version 2 with Classpath Exception?

Tags: licensing, gnu

[Netbeans 6.8 startup http://confusionstudio.com/eraseme/netbeans.png](http://confusionstudio.com/eraseme/netbeans.png)

I noticed this today, and I searched for it on Google, but I can't seem to find the `GNU Public License Version 2 with Classpath Exception`. Is it a new license? What does it cover?

**Edit:** I was originally kidding (and hadn't really Googled) because I thought this was a Netbeans error, but I see that the joke is on me: it's an exception to the GPLv2 when you link to the Netbeans lib on your classpath. Anyway, I'll leave this up since it might be useful to someone. Thanks Alex for the detailed answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googling your question gets the text of the licence:

http://openjdk.java.net/legal/gplv2+ce.html

Which states:

> As a special exception, the copyright holders of this library give you
>       permission to link this library with independent modules to produce an
>       executable, regardless of the license terms of these independent modules,
>       and to copy and distribute the resulting executable under terms of your
>       choice, provided that you also meet, for each linked independent module,
>       the terms and conditions of the license of that module.  An independent
>       module is a module which is not derived from or based on this library.  If
>       you modify this library, you may extend this exception to your version of
>       the library, but you are not obligated to do so.  If you do not wish to do
>       so, delete this exception statement from your version.

Comment: Wow, this is fascinating. Strange name, but so basically you can use the Netbeans lib with your own license. Good to know. BTW, I was originally kidding and didn't google because I thought it was an error in Netbeans. Silly me. Thanks, best answer and +1 and all that (though it's a CW, sorry).